# Julia: how to write a printing method for repl for a new array type?

Tags: julia

Apologies the code is a bit long but it's a MWE.

Say, I have defined a module which defines a new vector type called `CmpVector`. I want to override the text printed to the repo. So I've overwritten, print, show and display but it still prints its own thing. How do I overload the print to REPL for a new array??

```
module CmpVectors
    import Base:size,print,show,getindex, setindex!, display

    mutable struct CmpVector{T} <: AbstractVector{T}
        # compressed::Vector{UInt8}
        # vector_pointer::Ptr{T}
        inited::Bool
        # size::Tuple
    end

    size(pf::CmpVector{T}) where T = (1,)

    display(io::IO, pf::CmpVector{T}) where T = begin
        if pf.inited
            display(io, "NOO")
        else
            display(io, "Vector in compressed state")
        end
    end

    show(io::IO, pf::CmpVector{T}) where T = begin
        if pf.inited
            show(io, "NOO")
        else
            show(io, "Vector in compressed state")
        end
    end 

    print(io::IO, pf::CmpVector{T}) where T = begin
        if pf.inited
            show(io, "NOO")
        else
            print(io, "Vector in compressed state")
        end
    end

    getindex(pf::CmpVector{T}, i...) where T = zero(T)

end # module
```

I ran this

```
    using Revise
    using CmpVectors
    CmpVectors.CmpVector{Int}(true)
```

it prints

```
1-element CmpVectors.CmpVector{Int64}:
 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to overload the `show` which is in `Base` (`Base.show`), not define your own `show`. Also, you should specify which MIME type you are overloading.

```
mutable struct MyType
    val::Symbol
end

function Base.show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", mytype::MyType)
    println(io, "This is my type which contains $(mytype.val)")
end


MyType(:something)

## outputs
This is my type which contains something
```